# How to correctly use facebook scope to get user email?

Tags: php, facebook

I need to retrieve a user's email when they use facebook login on my website. Facebook has a `scope` parameter in their login URL that requests for these extended permissions. What exactly do I add to this code that will properly set scope to include email??

```
/**
* Get a Login URL for use with redirects. By default, full page redirect is
* assumed. If you are using the generated URL with a window.open() call in
* JavaScript, you can pass in display=popup as part of the $params.
*
* The parameters:
* - redirect_uri: the url to go to after a successful login
* - scope: comma separated list of requested extended perms
*
* @param Array $params provide custom parameters
* @return String the URL for the login flow
*/
public function getLoginUrl($params=array()) {
 $this->establishCSRFTokenState();
 $currentUrl = $this->getCurrentUrl();
 return $this->getUrl(
   'www',
   'dialog/oauth',
   array_merge(array(
                 'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                 'redirect_uri' => $currentUrl, // possibly overwritten
                 'state' => $this->state),
               $params));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the scope parameter:

```
public function getLoginUrl($params=array()) {
 $this->establishCSRFTokenState();
 $currentUrl = $this->getCurrentUrl();
 return $this->getUrl(
   'www',
   'dialog/oauth',
   array_merge(array(
                 'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                 'redirect_uri' => $currentUrl, // possibly overwritten
                 'state' => $this->state,
                 'scope'=>'email'),
               $params));
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'll accept this soon as I can. Do you know if Facebook allows apps/websites that use facebook login to store this information or is that against their policy? What CAN I store?

Comment: As far as I know, you are allowed to store user data, however Facebook recommends that you do not ask for permissions (and therefore more of their data) that isn't relative to your website or that you simply will not use.